# How to group multiples classes defined in several files in one package or namespace?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have c# background and learning python and I am confused between packages and namespace. I want to define number of classes in different .py files and some how they belong to same nsamespace (c# kind of namespace). How can I do it in python. I am using python tools and visualstudio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Each `.py` file is a "module."](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#modules) You can [define a package](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages), which is simply a collection of modules, rooted in some directory. The most important thing to note is that each subdirectory should contain an `__init.py__` file:

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as `string`, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__` variable, described later.

Comment: I have another question, what is best practice for defining classes. All relevant classes should be defined in a separate .py files or single .py file.

Comment: That's a completely different question, so you should [post it separately.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)